# Expo App crashes/shuts down when remote js debug is activated on SDK 39 for Android

Tags: debugging, react-native, expo

currently I try to debug my react native app via expo and its crash always when im clicking remote debug with JS
related to the issue fix for

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/10284

I follow the guide for resolving in the github comment:

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/10464#issuecomment-703178030

I upgraded my project to SDK 39 as following:

package.json as follow:

package.json looks now like that:

```
"dependencies": {
"expo": "~39.0.3",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.3.tar.gz",
"react-native-web": "~0.13.7"
},
```

expo --version => 3.27.13

I updated my android client for expo:

[image]

but it shows SDK 39.0.0 not SDK 39.0.3 as expected.

After that I deleted my packag-lock.json & clear npm_modules and clean npm caches.

Run npm install

When I debug my app now on the emulator my app & expo crashes.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's running now for me

"dependencies": {
"expo": "~39.0.2",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-dom": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "//https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.3.tar.gz",
"react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
},

1. Start Emulator
2. expo client:install:android
3. yarn start -c
4. Deploy app on device